# How to specify a different type to const generics parameters in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm going to make a generic type for coordinates. It should be able to specify the base number type for each axis.

At first, my code looks like this:

```
use num::Signed;

struct Coordinate<Index: Signed> {
  x: Index,
  y: Index,
}
```

Besides, I want it to carry extra bound information to help me check the access in the implementation, so I wrote this.

```
use num::Signed;

struct Coordinate<const Bound: isize, Index: Signed> {
  x: Index,
  y: Index,
}
```

However, even though `Signed` is only implemented for `i8, ..., isize`, I cannot simply compare a value of `Signed` with `isize`. So I turned to this:

```
use num::Signed;

struct Coordinate<const Bound: Index, Index: Signed> {
  x: Index,
  y: Index,
}
```

Of course, it failed. I wonder if there's any possible solution to this problem.

Comment: If your problem is just comparing `Bound: isize` with `x: impl Signed`, perhaps you could specify `Index: Signed + Into<isize>` and convert it to `isize` for comparison with the bound.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thank you! It does work in cases. But I may use the `Bound` to initialize fields, which require things like `TryFrom<isize>`. But it hasn't been implemented and I don't want to implement it manually in my code. I'm just making simple graph applications!

Comment: Oh, that's a new requirement. I gathered that `Bound` is only used for comparison. But what's wrong with `Index: Signed + Into<isize> + TryFrom<isize>`? I'd expect those bounds to be satisfied all relevant integer types.

Comment: @user4815162342 the compiler told me that "`<Index as TryFrom<isize>>::Error` doesn't implement `Debug`,
the trait `Debug` is not implemented for `<Index as TryFrom<isize>>::Error`"

Comment: You probably used something like `.try_into().unwrap()`. If you don't feel like further complicating the trait bounds, just replace the unwrap with `.unwrap_or_else(|_| unreachable!())`, and it should compile.

Comment: It might be worth showing an actual minimal usecase in your question to avoid XY problems and to make it possible to validate answers.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thank you it's helpful to eliminate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first version was going in the right direction, it just needs some more trait bounds:

```rust
use num::Signed;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Coordinate<const BOUND: isize, Index>
where
    Index: Signed + PartialOrd + Copy,
    isize: From<Index>,
{
    x: Index,
    y: Index,
}

impl<const BOUND: isize, Index> Coordinate<BOUND, Index>
where
    Index: Signed + PartialOrd + Copy,
    isize: From<Index>,
{
    pub fn new(x: Index, y: Index) -> Option<Self> {
        if x >= Index::zero()
            && y >= Index::zero()
            && isize::from(x) < BOUND
            && isize::from(y) < BOUND
        {
            Some(Self { x, y })
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(Coordinate::<10, i16>::new(5, 3));
    dbg!(Coordinate::<10, i16>::new(5, 11));
}
```

```
[src\main.rs:32] Coordinate::<10, i16>::new(5, 3) = Some(
    Coordinate {
        x: 5,
        y: 3,
    },
)
[src\main.rs:33] Coordinate::<10, i16>::new(5, 11) = None
```

Although `PartialOrd + Copy` seems tedious and are both already covered by [`PrimInt`](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/trait.PrimInt.html), so I would use that one instead.

Further, nothing in your question actually requires `Signed`, so I would remove it until actually needed.

```rust
use num::PrimInt;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Coordinate<const BOUND: isize, Index>
where
    Index: PrimInt,
    isize: From<Index>,
{
    x: Index,
    y: Index,
}

impl<const BOUND: isize, Index> Coordinate<BOUND, Index>
where
    Index: PrimInt,
    isize: From<Index>,
{
    pub fn new(x: Index, y: Index) -> Option<Self> {
        if x >= Index::zero()
            && y >= Index::zero()
            && isize::from(x) < BOUND
            && isize::from(y) < BOUND
        {
            Some(Self { x, y })
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(Coordinate::<10, i16>::new(5, 3));
    dbg!(Coordinate::<10, i16>::new(5, 11));
}
```

```
[src\main.rs:32] Coordinate::<10, i16>::new(5, 3) = Some(
    Coordinate {
        x: 5,
        y: 3,
    },
)
[src\main.rs:33] Coordinate::<10, i16>::new(5, 11) = None
```